# Show that t is a linear transformation of these polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, linear-transformations

I'm confused on how these substitutions are occurring. On the first line, it looks like $p(t)=p(t)+q(t)$ and $q(t)=t^2[p(t)+q(t)]$. Then on the second line, it looks like they're subbing $q(t)$ for $t^2p(t)$.

> Let $T : \mathbb{P}_2$ -> $\mathbb{P}_4$ be the transformation that
>   maps a polynomial $p(t)$ into the polynomial $p(t) + t^2 p(t)$. Show
>   that $T$ is a linear transformation.

[image]

Comment: They are not subbing $q(t)$ with $t^2[p(t)+q(t)]$, they are treating $p(t)+q(t)$ as $p(t)$ in the general case, and applying $T$ to it.

Comment: They aren't substitutions. The function $T$ maps a polynomial to a different polynomial, namely itself plus $t^2$ times itself. The first line is just applying this rule to the polynomial $p+q$. The second line is just rearranging things.

Comment: The notation is horrible & misleading. It would be better to write $(T(p))(t)$ instead of $T(p(t))$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray}
(T(p+q))(t) &=& (1+t^2)((p+q)(t)) \\
&=& (1+t^2)(p(t)+q(t)) \\
&=& (1+t^2) p(t) + (1+t^2) q(t)\\
&=& (T(p))(t)+(T(q))(t)
\end{eqnarray}
And so $T(p+q) = T(p)+T(q)$.

Similarly,
\begin{eqnarray}
(T(cp)(t)) &=& (1+t^2)((cp)(t)) \\
&=& (1+t^2)(c p(t)) \\
&=& c (1+t^2) p(t) \\
&=& c (T(p))(t)
\end{eqnarray}
And so $T(cp) = c T(p)$.