# Difference between number of scalars for proving linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, linear-transformations

Why did the solution to the first question only have one scalar, and the solution to the second had two scalars? Is it up to the solver's preference?

**Question 1:**

> Define $T : \mathbb{P}_3 \to \mathbb{R}^4$ by $$T(p) = \begin{bmatrix} p(-3) \\ p(-1) \\ p(1) \\ p(3) \end{bmatrix}$$ Show that $T$ is a linear transformation.

[image]

---

**Question 2:**

> Let $T : \mathbb{P}_2$ -> $\mathbb{P}_4$ be the transformation that
>   maps a polynomial $p(t)$ into the polynomial $p(t) + t^2 p(t)$. Show
>   that $T$ is a linear transformation.

[image]

Comment: Duplicate of [Prove that T is a linear transformation](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2209658/prove-that-t-is-a-linear-transformation) ***and*** [Show that t is a linear transformation of these polynomials](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2209632/show-that-t-is-a-linear-transformation-of-these-polynomials). To the OP: you may edit the already posted questions if/as needed, of course, but please do *not* repost them in duplicate.

Comment: Not quite a duplicate, but there is a lot that could be done to improve the formatting of this question (and the collective set of questions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When seeking to show that $T$ is a linear transformation, the following are equivalent:

- $T(\alpha x + \beta y) = \alpha T(x) + \beta T(y)$ for any scalars $\alpha, \beta$ and "vectors" $x,y$.
- $T(x+y) = T(x) + T(y)$ for any $x,y$ and $T(\alpha x) = \alpha T(x)$ for any $x$ and any scalar $\alpha$.

You should be able to prove the equivalence of these statements.

Comment: Would it matter if I started the proof with the right-hand side? As in $\alpha T(x) + \beta T(y) = T(\alpha x + \beta y)$ and $T(x) + T(y)=T(x+y), \alpha T(x) = T(\alpha x)$